# Create points at specified distance from each other in random fishnet's cells while being on linestrings

Tags: postgis, geoprocessing, qgis-processing, algorithm, vector-grid

We have a land protocol where we receive a fishnet of 1x1 km cells. Some cells are randomly choosed.
We need to put 4 points in each cell and these points have to be on a road too. The minimum distance between points have to be 500m for every points of every cells **IF POSSIBLE** or if it is not, we want the maximum possible distance.

In a first try we divided every cell in four 500x500 m cells with [ST_CreateFishnet](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiCreateFishnet) then we put points at the centroid of the sub-cells then on the closest road (ST_ClosestPoint). We get some good results but in the example below you can see than point 5 is too close from 6 and could be moved on the left road.

```
WITH
r1 AS (         -- only sub-cells which intersects random cells
    SELECT id_maille, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS id_grille, fishnet_500.geomgrille
    FROM fishnet_500
        JOIN t_mailles
            ON ST_Intersects(ST_Buffer(t_mailles.geom,-200), fishnet_500.geomgrille)     -- buffer < 0 to not select neightbours
)
,
r2 AS (         -- cut roads in every cells
SELECT id_maille, id_grille, ST_Intersection((ST_Dump(roads.geom)).geom, r1.geomgrille) as geomroute
FROM roads
    JOIN r1
        ON ST_Intersects(roads.geom, r1.geomgrille)
)
                -- select point on each road the closest to cell centroid
SELECT r2.id_maille, r2.id_grille, ST_ClosestPoint(ST_Union(r2.geomroute),ST_Centroid(r1.geomgrille)) as geomipa
FROM r2
    JOIN r1
        ON r2.id_grille = r1.id_grille
GROUP BY r2.id_maille, r2.id_grille, r1.geomgrille
ORDER BY r2.id_maille, r2.id_grille
```

If you want to give it a try I put the 3 layers (fishnet with random cells, sub-fisnet and roads) in an archive that you can find [here](http://partage2.observatoire-environnement.org/public/fb018f).

I guess we can't avoid a recursive algorithm that tries many possibilities but i'm not sure.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code that you have used so far?

Comment: Are there any other constraints? It would make it easier, for example, to start with a point in the furthest corner of sub-cell, making it less likely you'll have to discard other points for being too close?

Comment: Yes it is good to start with points in corners when there are no other cells touching the cell on the considered corner. Points have to be at a minimum distance from each other on the whole grid.

Answer (score 2):

Are you willing to do this in R or python by linking to your PostGIS database?  If you used ST_DumpPoints on all the lines in each 1x1 km cell, you should be able to use one of many available algorithms to select 4 points with the distance between each > 500m, or as far apart as possible.

Perhaps one of the algorithms mentioned on Wikipedia for the knapsack problem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem, will give you some ideas.  Or, I think an MCMC algorithm would work well.

If two grids abut each other, does the distance between points in the adjacent grids matter?

Comment: To anwser your last question. Yes, as said in my last comment : "Points have to be at a minimum distance from each other on the whole grid". Thank you for your help.